# WPF C# Image control cutted/disapeared below 540 pixels

Tags: c#, wpf, image, geometry, controls

For some reason, image control doesn't show below 540 pixels

if the image control top margin below 540 pixels of the window it disappears
if it under then it cut below 540 pixels

Сould not find anything for a solution

[2 images of clock cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMzx9.jpg)

C#
code

```
        TimeZoneInfo newyorkZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        double time44 = Convert.ToDouble(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, newyorkZone).ToString("HH"));

        if (time44 >= 12) time44 = time44 - 12;
     
        double time444 = Convert.ToDouble(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, newyorkZone).ToString("mm"));
        
        double time44rad = (time44 * 360 / 12) * Math.PI / 180 - Math.PI / 2;
        double time444rad = (time444 * 360 / 60) * Math.PI / 180 - Math.PI / 2;
     

        double xtime444 = 125 + 125 * Math.Cos(time444rad);
        double ytime444 = 125 + 125 * Math.Sin(time444rad);
       
        xtime44 = Math.Round(xtime44, 0);
        int xitime44 = Convert.ToInt32(xtime44);
        
        ytime44 = Math.Round(ytime44, 0);
        int yitime44 = Convert.ToInt32(ytime44);
       
        xtime444 = Math.Round(xtime444, 0);
        int xitime444 = Convert.ToInt32(xtime444);
       
        ytime444 = Math.Round(ytime444, 0);
        int yitime444 = Convert.ToInt32(ytime444);

        int xi = 125;
        int yi = 125;

        GeometryGroup clock4 = new GeometryGroup();
  
        clock4.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(xi, yi), 125, 125));
       
        clock4.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(xi, yi), new Point(xitime44, yitime44)));
        clock4.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(xi, yi), new Point(xitime444, yitime444)));
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3);
  
        GeometryDrawing aGeometryDrawing4 = new GeometryDrawing();
        aGeometryDrawing4.Geometry = clock4;
        aGeometryDrawing4.Pen = pen;
     
        DrawingGroup aDrawingGroup4 = new DrawingGroup();
      
        aDrawingGroup4.Children.Add(aGeometryDrawing4);
      
        DrawingImage geometryImage4 = new DrawingImage(aDrawingGroup4);

        geometryImage4.Freeze();
  
        cap4time.Source = geometryImage4;
```

Xaml

```
        <Image x:Name="cap1time" Margin="100,50" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Image x:Name="cap3time" Margin="100,500" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Image x:Name="cap4time" Margin="600,500" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        <Image x:Name="cap2time" Margin="600,50" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Comment: Positioning WPF controls using their Margins is never a good idea - place each image in a different row / column of a Grid control.

Comment: it means I need to add grid and split it, then add image controls in separate row/ column without Marging?

Comment: Yes, for example https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

Comment: Thank you, it helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

this helped me thanks to Peregrine

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1320"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="530"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="cap1time" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Image x:Name="cap2time" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Image x:Name="cap3time" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Image x:Name="cap4time" Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
            
        </Grid>
```